# Images URLs Rewriting

Tags: php, html, image, url

I have written a script image.php that is quite long, but I've just copied a portion of the code below.

Note that:

```
$image = $_GET['ph'];
$w = $_GET['w'];
```

So that:

```
function getImage_w($image, $w){
    $ext = strrchr($image, ".");
    if (strtolower($ext) == '.jpg' || strtolower($ext) == '.jpeg'){
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

        $src_im_jpg = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        $size = getimagesize($image);

        $src_w = $size[0];
        $src_h = $size[1];
        $dst_w = $w;
        $dst_h = round(($dst_w/$src_w)*$src_h);
        $dst_im = imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w,$dst_h);

        imagecopyresampled($dst_im,$src_im_jpg,0,0,0,0,$dst_w,$dst_h,$src_w,$src_h);

        imagejpeg($dst_im);
    }
}
```

This script takes a two GET variables, `$_GET['ph']` and `$_GET['w']`, `ph` defines the URL of the image, and `w` defines the destination resize width.

For example: If my script is in a `libs/` directory, and my photos are in a `resources` directory, and I want to display my photo with `width = 100`, I have to use this html:

```
<img src="libs/image.php?ph=../resources/myimage.jpg&w=100">
```

My problem is, my images appear in the browser correctly, but with a bad url format. I'd like to put images `alt` attribute instead of this url in the images property.

And to automatically apply the `image.php` for an image request.

Also, I have a problem when the user wants to save the image in his desktop, the image saves under a name `image.php`, which is not desirable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question... You want the src of the the image file to be a different URL? can you give an example?

Comment: I've edited the question to be clearer

Comment: Please format your code for readability. `:)`

Comment: @BrianGlaz - I believe the OP is trying to prettify his image URL's to remove the GET string part.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Ok, I got it now. Simo... are you familiar with .htaccess and mod rewrite? This should help you do what you want

Comment: @brian , yeah I've already done that .htaccess stuff with urls of the website.
The problem is that I've done that according using the ids of the elements ... images don't have Ids

Comment: @brian, for e.g : an item with an id=3 , have a url to access : ?id=3

rewritten as : 3_item_title.html

But how can I use an Id to rewrite image URL when I don't have id?

Comment: Usually, when you do something like this for a rewrite, you make the positions in the URL meaningful. In other words, `http://example.com/image/[path-with-dashes-instead-of-slashes]/[filename-jpg]/[dimensionw-dimensiony]/`, with `/image/` representing the `image.php` script. And then I believe you can manipulate the filename on save with a header directive.

Comment: Thank you @Jared , I think your solution will be useful for me  : +1 +1 +1 :-)

Comment: I hope you've got some security in place to prevent someone downloading content they shouldn't be (including server files and scripts). `:)`

Comment: Actually , the image downloads in a .php form ,but when I open it, contains only unknown characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
#change 'resize' to the folder your image.php is in
RewriteBase /resize

#e.g. /resize/path/to/image/sample-200.jpg
# will become /resize/image.php?ph=path/to/image/sample.jpg&w=200
RewriteRule ^(.*)-([0-9]+)(\.jpg)$ image.php?ph=$1$3&w=$2 [L,NC]
```

Note that you can't use .. in the url, so instead use root-relative url. To do this you need to add the document_root the the path in you php file:

```
$image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . str_replace('..','', $_GET['ph']);
```

Users saving the image will get the normal image name, but with a '-' and the size added to the end.

Not sure what you want with the alt. Also I don't think it is wise to rewrite all images, so this script only rewrites images the start with /resize/...

www.example.com/hosting.jpg is not possible, as the php doesn't know in which folder to look for this image, and to what size to resize it.

Comment: Thank you @Gerben , I will really try this solutions , thank you again :-) +1 ,